# Emploi de « en » et « y » avec des noms animés

Tags: pronoms, en, y

> Benoît est absent. Je parle souvent de lui, je pense à lui.

La variante ci-après est correcte (ou au moins tolérée) ?

> Benoît est absent. J'en parle souvent, j'y pense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ici,

> j'en parle souvent

appuie le fait que tu parle souvent de l'absence de Benoit, plutôt que de Benoit lui même ; idem pour

> j'y pense

Ta première phrase est donc celle à utiliser si tu veux référer à Benoit et non à son absence :)